# How to fix React-tab issues

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-tabs

I am trying to implement react tabs in my Next.js applications. I have installed react tab packages and put the code but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

[image]

When I click on title 1 it doesn't move any content 1 same as clicking title2.

But the same code works in a new React application. Below is the code:

```
const Rtab = () => {
  return(    
    <Tabs>
      <TabList>
        <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
        <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel>
        <h2>Any content 1</h2>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <h2>Any content 2</h2>
      </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
  );      
}
```

Comment: Could you show us all your `Tabs`, `TabList`, `Tab`, and `TabPanel` implementation?

Comment: now it works but i want to change its style. I mean how to modify style of tab1 and tab2? I just want a pink border bottom

Comment: Could you share the entire file of your implementation?

Comment: Look i have adde the tab componenet code. here i just want to modify the Tabs style. Tab is now workin

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue. Can you tell me how you got it fixed?